# Selenium Webdriver. Mouse actions inaccuracy in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: testing, selenium, mouse, webdriver

Greetings to all!

I'm not a native English speaker, so excuse me for my fair grammar.

Selenium is a framework for testing web applications in different browsers. I want to ask people, who are using Selenium, for any help. I was asking people in Selenium's Google Group, but nobody helped me.

I'm working on the project with a lot of mouse interaction using Selenium Webdriver. I'm writing tests on C#. When my team started to use Selenium Webdriver, we noticed, that mouse actions (OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions) have a bit unexpected behavior in IE and work differently in different browsers (and even on different machines). For first time I was the only tester that was working with mouse actions. I was blaming Selenium Webdriver and I was trying to find the way to avoid this inaccuracy. I was investigating this problem for a long time, but without any result. But I don't want to spend your time on prehistory.

Ok, let me describe the situation. We created the demo project: the simple page with . And we implemented the possibility to paint on this canvas by holding left mouse button. So I hope that it's pretty clear for you.

The next important thing is that we enabled logging to console. That is, we can see coordinates of mouse arrow inside canvas by opening console.

Then we wrote a test:

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver); 
a.Build(); 
a.MoveToElement(canvas, 100, 100) 
 .ClickAndHold() 
 .MoveByOffset(100, 0) 
 .Release(); 
a.Perform();
```

The code is quite simple. Just moving mouse arrow to the canvas, then offset mouse arrow by (100, 100) and then move vertically by 100 (with holded left mouse button). As you can understand, the result in logs should be (200, 100).

But here is the most interesting thing: my colleagues have the same result (200, 100)! But they had inaccuracy 1 month ago (that's why we thought, that mouse actions work inaccurate). And I still have inaccurate result: (192, 96). So there is 4px error per 100px of offset. My colleagues don't understand, what they have changed and why mouse actions work correctly now or them.

One more interesting thing is that visually (I remind you, that we can paint on the canvas) it's absolutely 100px (we hold mouse button when moving mouse arrow vertically)! Amazing!

So, that's the experiment.

I ask any appropriate people to help me with this problem. It appears only in IE9. And I want to understand the reason of that behavior. How Actions class is implemented? Can it depends on mouse driver or something like that? In this case, if it's matter, I'm using wireless mouse and it has a special driver. Please, help me!

P.S. I was trying to change settings of my mouse, settings of my screen, but no results.

Thank you!

Best regards,
Michael Kalygin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the zoom level in IE9 is set to 100% - that's the only thing I can think of that would offset your coordinates by 4%.

Comment: Oh my god! This is incredible, but seems, that this is the reason. I was reinstalling IE for few times... I was looking at settings and didn't notice it...

Probably, IE sets it to 105% by default! Be attentive, if you find the same problem on your computer!

Big thanks! You are awesome! :)

P.S.: so stupid... really... I'm sorry! All bugs are always stupid! :)

Comment: It will still work in IE9 i.e. with lower zoom levels. You have to implement below code: /n <code>var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\SeleniumDrivers");
            var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
            {
                IgnoreZoomLevel = true
            };</code>

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified the sequence of actions to fit my needs.  It works great for IE8 but Firefox and Chrome do not like it.  I am trying to drag and drop an element by some offset (100,100) but FireFox throws an exception saying the target is out of bounds and gives some crazy coordinate numbers that do not match what I am doing.  Chrome just doesn't move the element.

My problem is that the graph is a third party widget that uses svg for chrome and Firefox.  In IE I could use common techniques for finding "cells" on the graph, but Firefox and Chrome do not allow me to find an element(cells) by Id, Class or anything.  So I have a javascriptExecutor that I can use to get all graph cells data including x,y position of cell on the graph widget.  I can get the graph widget location as there is a "wrapper div" for the graph.  using the graph location I do the following:

```
Point mxPoint = driver.GetElementPosition(GraphicalDisplayPage.GraphDisplayPaneById);
Actions moveCell = new Actions(driver);

moveCell.Build();
moveCell.MoveByOffset(mxPoint.X, mxPoint.Y);//move mouse to upper left corner of graph
moveCell.MoveByOffset(xOfCelltoMove, yOfCellToMove);//move mouse to cell we want to move
moveCell.ClickAndHold();//select cell and hold it
moveCell.MoveByOffset(100, 100);//drag cell
moveCell.Release();//drop it
moveCell.Perform();//run this set of actions
```

Ok I figured out my problem.  I need to get the size of the graph element and divde Height and Width by 2 and negate those values for negative offsets.  Then my first Move is to the graph element's location (center of element) then move to the negated offsets to get upper left corner, then move by offset to xOfCelltomove and yOfcelltomove.  and I am good to go.  I also added 10 to both xOfCellToMove and yOfCellToMove to get mouse over the element vs over left corner of element making it more consistent so the Actions look like this:

```
Size mxSize = driver.GetElementSize(GraphicalDisplayPage.JGraphDisplayPaneById);
mxSize.Height = -(mxSize.Height/2);
mxSize.Width = -(mxSize.Width/2);

//create the action and do it
Actions moveCell = new Actions(driver);

moveCell.Build();
moveCell.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(GraphicalDisplayPage.JGraphDisplayPaneById)) //mxPoint.X, mxPoint.Y) //move mouse to center of graph

.MoveByOffset(mxSize.Width, mxSize.Height)//move mouse to top left corner of graph                    
.MoveByOffset(xOfCelltoMove , yOfCellToMove) //move mouse to cell we want    
.ClickAndHold() //select cell and hold it
.MoveByOffset(100, 100) //drag cell
.Release();//drop it

moveCell.Perform();//run this set of actions
```